# php simple string regex replacement

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have this string: "4702819 - 09" (without the quotes) and i want to make a pattern to change it to :
"094702819". So basically to remove the space-space completely and to cut what came after it
to be at the beginning. So another example would be:

"5502819 - 098" to "0985502819" etc. How do i do that? do i use preg replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = "4702819 - 09";
$pattern = '/(\d+) - (\d+)/i';
$replacement = '$2$1';
print preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

The above will output `094702819`. See the [PHP manual on `preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for additional examples.

Comment: @Kristian Antonsen: bad bet;-) if you know what i mean

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it would be:

```
$string = "4702819 - 09";
$arr = explode(" - ", $string);
$newString = $arr[1].$arr[0];
echo $newString;
```